# how to fix the below error while using Extent Report cucumber-adapter 4?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, extentreports

I did the extent report cucumber-adapter 4 configuration in my project, but i am getting the following error while run and it caused by cucumber/api/event/ConcurrentEventListener- it says NOclassFound error. and  I have added my runner class, Pom.Xml and the exception what i got.But before adding this configuration I am able to run my code.
Can you suggest how to fix this issue? Exception is:

````
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberExcepti`enter code here`on: Couldn't load plugin class: com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter          
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.loadClass(PluginOption.java:122)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.lambda$parsePluginName$1(PluginOption.java:108)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:108)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parse(PluginOption.java:95)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:226)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:63)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addPlugins(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:86)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:41)
                    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:122)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
                    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
                    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
                    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
                    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
                    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
                    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
                    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
                    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
                    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
                    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/event/ConcurrentEventListener
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
                    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.loadClass(PluginOption.java:114)
                    ... 23 more
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.event.ConcurrentEventListener
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    ... 36 more
                
                
                Process finished with exit code 255
            
            
            and my runner class is:
            
            package runner;
            
            import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
            import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
            
            @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
            @CucumberOptions(
                    
                    features = {"src/test/resources"}, glue = {"stepDefs"}, tags= "@functionalTesting",
                    dryRun = false,
                    monochrome = true,
                    plugin ={"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:src/test/extent-Report/YoCoBoard-Report/extent.html"}
            
            )
            class RunnerTest {
            
             
            }
        
        this is my pom.xml
        
        
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>org.yoco.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>YoCoS</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
        
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
        
        <!--                    <parallel>methods</parallel>-->
        <!--                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        
            <dependencies>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                    <version>3.141.59</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.5.0</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.13</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                    <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
                    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.5</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                    <version>5.7.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
                    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.12</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
        
            </dependencies>
        
        
        </project>```
````

Comment: Please share your pom.xml.